# Is the zero locus of $X_0X_1+X_0X_2+X_1X_2$ an analytic subvariety?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space, complex-manifolds

I am trying to understand an example that my professor introduced. At the time, I thought that I understood it:

Consider $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with homogeneous coordinates $X_0$, $X_1$, and $X_2$ and let $C\subset\mathbb{CP}^2$ satisfy $X_0X_1+X_0X_2+X_1X_2=0$.

Is $C$ an analytic subvariety?

We defined an analytic subvariety of a complex manifold as "a subset given locally as the zeros of a finite collection of holomorphic functions".

Since $P(X_0,X_1,X_2)=X_0X_1+X_0X_2+X_1X_2$ is homogeneous of degree $2$, we have that $C$ is well-defined.

I believe that it suffices to show that $P$ is holomorphic, but I am having trouble:

Let $(U_0,\varphi_0)$ be a standard chart. Then $\left(P\circ\varphi_0^{-1}\right)\left(\left(X_1,X_2\right)\right)=P\left(\left[1,X_1,X_2\right]\right)$ is not well-defined on $U_0$.

Am I missing something?

Here, $U_0=\{[X_0,X_1,X_2]:X_0\neq0\}$ and $\varphi_0:U_0\to\mathbb C^2$ is defined by

$$\left[X_0,X_1,X_2\right]\mapsto\left(\frac{X_1}{X_0},\frac{X_2}{X_0}\right).$$

Comment: In fact $P([1,X_1,X_2])$ _is_ well-defined on $U_0$, since if you fix the first homogeneous coordinate of a point, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uniquely determined.

Comment: @Nefertiti, can I then legally say that $P([X_0,X_1,X_2])=X_1/X_0+X_2/X_0+X_1/X_0\cdot X_2/X_0$? In this case, $P$ is holomorphic on every chart, which is what I wanted to show.

Comment: Dear Josue, what you wrote is $P/X_0^2$ rather than $P$. And indeed this is exactly what you want: since $P$ and $X_0^2$ are homogeneous of degree 2, $P/X_0^2$ is a well-defined rational function, regular on $U_0$, whose zero-locus in $U_0$ is exactly $C \cap U_0$.